# objectdatasource not always firing select function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing this query for the issue i am having with object datasource control .In the following link similar issue already been discussed but not the same .

[ObjectDataSource.Select() not always firing on page postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593015/objectdatasource-select-not-always-firing-on-page-postback)

In my case this could not be resolved with the solution mentioned there  (**GridView.Databind**)

- **Problem:**

In My Project UI pages(aspx or ascx) pages calls a DAL manager functions one of the function is `SelectTasks(int userID)` which is assigned to selectMethod of Objectdatasource control. For some reason i have to call this SelectTasks function with the help of object datsourcecontrol as below .

```
objectdatasourceSelectTasks.SelectParameters.Item("UserID") = textBoxUserID.text

    IEnumerator i = objectdatasourceSelectTasks.Select.GetEnumerator()
```

and convert this enumerator value to the list .

I have kept debug point at the DAL function sometimes this debug point was not hit. But for the same record if i try to debug step by step i.e `objectdatasourceSelectTasks.Select` from here if i press F11 it is working. 
How can this be resolved ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we could not find an answer for this one , As a workaround we have called directly `DALManager` function .

```
Dim myObject As ArrayList

myObject = dalDataBridge.SelectTasks(textBoxUserID.text)
```